# Sprite kit: character movement set by draging him across the screen ( x axis) but stay at a set ( y position)

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Xcode
Sprite kit:

How do I make my :

```
-(SKSpriteNode*) createcharacter{
    SKSpriteNode *character = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Character.png"];
    character.position = CGPointMake(164, 67);
    character.name = @"Character";
}
```

And let my character be moved left and right, when he´s dragged?

I need him to stay at a set y position, but the x position is changed by the drag.

Thanks for answers :)

here´s how i did it in regular xcode: (unsure how to do it with sprite kit)

```
UITouch *Drag = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
character.center = [Drag locationInView:self.view];

if (character.center.y > 472) {
    character.center = CGPointMake(character.center.x, 472);       
}

if (character.center.y < 472) {
    character.center = CGPointMake(character.center.x, 472);
}    

if (character.center.x < 21) {
    character.center = CGPointMake(21, character.center.y);
}


if (character.center.x > 299) {
    character.center = CGPointMake(299, character.center.y);        
}
```

Comment: character.position = CGPointMake(x, 200); assuming 200 is your set y pos

Comment: can you go more in detail? i have added my code for this in "regular" xcode. but I am unsure how to work this out with sprite kit ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SKScene:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint positionInScene  = [touch locationInNode:self];
    CGPoint previousPosition = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];
    CGPoint translation = CGPointMake(positionInScene.x - previousPosition.x,
                                      positionInScene.y - previousPosition.y);

    // Animate the ship up or down based on finger position.
    [self moveCharacterWithTranslation:translation];
}

- (void)moveCharacterWithTranslation:(CGPoint)translation {
    // Animate the ship up or down based on finger position.

    [character runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction moveByX:translation.x y:0 duration:0.4f]]]];
}
```